# Facebook Gameroom Unity Trial Game Integration

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

i'm trying to integrate NonConsumable purchase in my app.

Currently i'm using:

-Unity 5.4.1f1

-Facebook SDK 7.9.0

I tried to use this guide:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gameroom/premium

but there was no FB.Arcade in my SDK. Is there another way to make my game trial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Premium Games page now states that this feature will only be available starting in January, their exact text is: ["Premium Games is a beta feature subject to change, and will only be available from the start of Jan 2017."](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gameroom/premium)

Secondly, the beta versions of Unity, like the one they have listed [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gameroom/requirements) and Unity 5.6 beta use a different unreleased version of the Facebook SDK. (7.9.4) This is probably why you're not seeing FB.Arcade.